# how to filter sql query results with matching string

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a database table in which one column contain the string value that is looks like dictionary in php.

Table:College

```
Id  name    requirement
1   x   {"users": ["A", "B"], "name": "*", "pool": "CSE", "place": "Bangalore"}
2   y   {"users": ["A", "C"], "name": "*", "pool": "CSE", "place": "Chennai"}
3   z   {"users": ["A", "B"], "name": "*", "pool": "ECE", "place": "Bangalore"}
4   r   {"users": ["A", "D"], "name": "*", "pool": "EEE", "place": "UP"}
```

From this table I need to filter only those rows in which the requirements column contain “pool”:”CSE”.
That is if pool is CSE or pool is ECE etc .

Currently my php code for fetching whole table is:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM waitqueue";
    $result = mysql_query($query);

    echo "[";
    echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        echo "," . json_encode($row);
    echo "]";
```

I dont want to change the above sql query.Because I need both conditions(full table and selected pool rows) from single query.So I wish to parse from results.

How to match the "pool" and how can I filter those rows?

Any one please suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your mysql version?

Comment: This is a very strange architecture... If you want to use a property for filtering, then you should not hide it deep in a serialized column value but as a separate column or reference, so that you can create an index on that. There are extensions for mysql that allow to access json encoded columns, but this does not change the fact that your architecture is strange. You should think about changing that, since the current setup won't scale. For a quick workaround you can simply create a wrapper function around the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function for the filtering.

Comment: my sql version:5.6.17

Comment: Only option is to unserialize all that and use array function to search it.You`ll have to get all the data each time,so consider normalizing your data.

Comment: Can you put some examples? and also can we use string functions to find the pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can filter like this

```
WHERE requirement LIKE '%"pool": "CSE"%'
```

But this is very big crutch :)

It is prefer to separate column requirement to columns: name, pool, place.
Than you may filter like this, for example:

```
WHERE pool = "CSE"
```

Other method is to filter rows in your while cycle like this

```
$output = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $requirement = json_decode($row['requirement'], true);
    if ($requirement['pool'] === 'CSE') {
        $output .= $output ? ', ' : '';
        $output .= json_encode($row);
    }
}
$output = '[' . $output . ']';
echo $output;
```

Comment: thanks for the response.But I dont have permisiion to spilt the database.can you suggest me any other way?

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns one row, therefore you need cycle for reading all rows

Comment: I tried your code..But its not working.I think the problem is with comma in `echo ",".json_encode($row);`Can you please tell me how to resolve this? That is for our case we dont need `echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));` this statement

Comment: `$requirement['pool']` contains data like this: `{"users": ["A", "B"], "name": "*", "pool": "CSE", "place": "Bangalore"}`. It is JSON data. `json_decode($row['requirement'], true)` converts JSON string into associative array.

Comment: Please see the code in the question.There I am using the statement `echo json_encode(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));` before while loop.But for our case no need of this line,because we are filtering with pool.So the comma in `echo "," . json_encode($row);` in your answer should be placed correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95989/discussion-between-mnv-and-nithya-k).

Comment: What do you need in result? echo rows with correct JSON format? Answer edited for this purpose.

Comment: Wow..its working..Thank you mnv..But for full table I put my code in else part and for pool I put your code in if part..Else part is not working now..:-(